# SwiftUI: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

I am following Stanford's CS193p Developing Apps for iOS online course.
I'm trying to do the [Assignment 6 (Memorize Themes.pdf)](https://cs193p.sites.stanford.edu/sites/g/files/sbiybj16636/files/media/file/assignment_6.pdf).

When I run my app in simulator and in edit mode tap on a list row to bring up the sheet, I get the following fatal error:
Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

**Question: Why the index matching** `themeToEdit` **inside themes array is nil?**

Please help me.

```
import SwiftUI

// Required Task 3: Your Memorize application should now show a “theme chooser” UI when it launches.

struct ThemeChooserView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var themeStore: ThemeStore
    
    @State private var editMode: EditMode = .inactive
        
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(themeStore.themes) { theme in
                    NavigationLink(destination: EmojiMemoryGameView(game: EmojiMemoryGame(theme: theme))) {
                        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                            Text(theme.name)
                                .foregroundColor(theme.color)
                                .font(.title)
                            Text(themeCardsDescription(theme: theme))
                        }
                        .gesture(editMode == .active ? tapGesture(theme: theme) : nil)
                    }
                }
                .onDelete { indexSet in
                    themeStore.themes.remove(atOffsets: indexSet)
                }
                .onMove { indexSet, newOffset in
                    themeStore.themes.move(fromOffsets: indexSet, toOffset: newOffset)
                }
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $isEditing) {
                let currentThemeIndex = themeStore.themes.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == themeToEdit?.id})
                ThemeEditor(theme: $themeStore.themes[currentThemeIndex!]) // ERROR: -  Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
            }
            .navigationTitle("Memorize")
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                    plusButton
                }
                ToolbarItemGroup {
                    EditButton()
                }
            }
            .environment(\.editMode, $editMode)
        }
    }
    
    @State private var isEditing: Bool = false
    
    @State private var themeToEdit: Theme?

    private func tapGesture(theme: Theme) -> some Gesture {
        TapGesture().onEnded { _ in
            themeToEdit = theme
            isEditing = true
        }
    }
    
    private func themeCardsDescription(theme: Theme) -> String {
        let numberOrAll = theme.numberOfPairsOfCards == theme.emojis.count ? "All" : "\(theme.numberOfPairsOfCards)"
        return numberOrAll + " pairs from \(theme.emojis.joined(separator: ""))"
    }
    
    private var plusButton: some View {
        Button {
            let theme = Theme(name: "New Theme", emojis: ["", ""], numberOfPairsOfCards: 2, color: .black)
            themeStore.themes.append(theme)
        } label: {
            Image(systemName: "plus")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you make sure everything worked as expected before the failing code using the debugger and/or print statements?

Comment: When I change `ThemeEditor(theme: $themeStore.themes[currentThemeIndex!])` to `ThemeEditor(theme: $themeStore.themes[0])`, there's no error. But of course it always shows first theme, not the one tapped on.

Comment: Where do you activate edit mode?

Comment: With `EditButton()` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/editbutton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the value because the value is probably to set yet, due to the mechanics of `@State` which gets triggers the observers on `willSet`, not `didSet`. To fix your issue you could get rid of the `isEditing` property and rely entirely on the `themeToEdit` property.

```swift
.sheet(item: $themeToEdit) { theme in
    let index = themeStore.themes.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == theme.id })
    ThemeEditor(theme: $themeStore.themes[index!])
}
```

Updated `tapGesture` implementation.

```swift
private func tapGesture(theme: Theme) -> some Gesture {
    TapGesture().onEnded { _ in
        themeToEdit = theme
    }
}
```

Documentation: [sheet(item:onDismiss:content:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/sheet(item:ondismiss:content:))

Comment: Thank you!!! The first version is working: `.sheet(item: $themeToEdit) { theme in
    let index = themeStore.themes.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == theme.id })
    ThemeEditor(theme: $themeStore.themes[index!])
}` The second one gives me error: "Cannot convert value of type 'Theme' to expected argument type 'Binding<Theme>'"

Comment: Oh right, I blindly guessed the type of argument you need to pass to the `ThemeEditor`. I will remove that :)